# Internal memory of my Moto E is almost full even after uninstalling and disabling so many apps. Will rooting it out help? If yes, then how?

Tags: root-access, internal-storage, motorola, motorola-moto-e

I feel that in 2-3 months my phone will stop even updating the existing very few apps. So I am thinking about rooting it. But even if I root my phone will I be able to do something to fix this internal memory problem? If I can fix this, then I am in need of the possible ways (After the root).

Comment: No... Rooting will not "help" reduce space usage, in fact it will require space for the SuperSU app. Have you checked our insufficient storage tags and wiki?

Comment: @acejavelin I have already rooted and flashed my phone with Marshmallow based custom ROM. Now I use adopted storage feature of marshmallow.

Comment: Sorry... Just popped up in my feed like a new post. Glad it's working for you